# Проблема с переустановкой jdk на eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

После смены jdk6 на jdk7 каждый раз при включении eclipse вываливает ошибка

> jre version 1.6.0 version 1.7.0 or later is needed to run google plugin for eclipse

В принципе, все проекты работают нормально, но хотелось бы избавиться от этого окна. В чем проблема? Читал, что подобное на маках бывает, но у меня обычный пк.

Comment: В глобальных переменных в JAVA_HOME стоит путь к новому jdk?

Comment: Да, путь верный

Comment: [Пробовали?][1]


  [1]: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-plugin-eclipse/V4MaZEXY24Q/rYhZf9MOttEJ

Comment: @имя слишком коротко У меня Kepler

Comment: Посмотрите какой у вас стоит JRE (run time Java). Забейте с командной строки:

    java -version

Comment: java version "1.7.0_51"